# Поставили минус за ответ. Получил -2 репутации. Почему не -10?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Ссылка на вопрос [создание чата на node.js на хостинге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825796/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-node-js-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5/825831#825831)

Comment: Потому что минус за ответ = -2.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @vp_arth "вы проголосовали против ответа: −1"

Comment: @Suvitruf, это когда ты голосуешь - у тебя снимается 1, а у того против кого - 2

Comment: @Suvitruf, Цитирую: "Поставили минус за ответ". Обычно это не первое лицо мн.ч, а третье. Хотя...

Comment: @Grundy а, прочитал вопрос как "поставил". mb D: